# How to save python code (part of the notebook) to file in GDrive from code

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colabs for my research in machine learning.
I do many variations on a network and run them saving the results.

I have a part of my notebook that used to be separate file (network.py) At the start of a training session I used to save this file in a directory that has the results and logs etc. Now that this part of the code is in the notebook it is easier to edit etc, BUT I do not have a file to copy to the output directory that describes the model. how to i take a section of a google colab notebook and save the raw code as a python file?

Things I have tried:
%%writefile "my_file.py" - is able to write the file however the classes are not available to the runtime.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @jess can you please explain what you mean by "on topic?" your comment is non-specific unlike the question.